# Adding a linked server via Powershell

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

I'm trying to add a linked server to my local SQL Server 2008 R2 setup from within a Powershell script.
Here's what I've been trying so far (and variants):

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
@rmtsrvname = N'<RemoteComputerName>', 
@useself=N'False' ,
@locallogin = N'domain\username' ,
@rmtuser = N'username',
@rmtpassword = N'password';
GO
```

The linking seems to work out alright, but as soon as I try to execte a query (using Invoke-Sqlcmd in Powershell), I receive an error saying that the login failed.

UPDATE:
I've also tried linking the servers and executing a simple query in the SQL Server Management Studio. I receive the same results, so the problem isn't likely related to Powershell.
Furthermore, I can query against linked servers if I set @useself to true. However, this condition won't always hold in practice (ie my script shouldn't require all the servers to be logged in as the same user).

Am I missing something?

Comment: In powershell is there an object for linked servers in the `SQL:` drive? I can't remember off the top of my head, but that could help with some interactive debugging

Comment: Can you, using the same user account, successfully perform the same action with `sqlcmd.exe` (or other SQL Server tool)? (Ie. is this a PowerShell issue, or a SQL access issue?)

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth your time checking out the [SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx).  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162234.aspx) is an example of how you can create Link Servers via SMO:

```
#Get a server object which corresponds to the default instance
$svr = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server

#Create a linked server object which corresponds to an OLEDB type of SQL server product
$lsvr = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.LinkedServer -argumentlist $svr,"OLEDBSRV"

#When the product name is SQL Server the remaining properties are not required to be set. 
$lsvr.ProductName = "SQL Server"

#Create the Database Object
$lsvr.Create()
```

You can specify the credentials for your local SQL server using a [ServerConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.aspx) object and for the linked server using a [LinkedServerLogin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.linkedserverlogin.aspx) object.